# .NET: How to group by multiple properties?

Tags: c#, .net, math, group-by

Given the following flattened "Mapping" class with Properties "UserId" and "PermissionId".

Lets say I have a Set<Mapping> with 5 items:

| UserId | PermissionId |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| A | Y |
| B | X |
| B | Y |
| B | Z |

And I want it to be grouped for the UI like this (lets call it "Row" class with properties List<UserId> "UserIds" and List<PermissionId> "PermissionIds"):

| UserIds | PermissionIds |
| --- | --- |
| A, B | X, Y |
| B | Z |

How would I group the Set<Mapping> to a List<Row>? I got no clue how to do it. I mean, is this more math or can it be done kind of easily by .NET?

I know it can be done very easily for the following outcome with GroupBy but I get no further:

| UserIds | PermissionIds |
| --- | --- |
| A | X, Y |
| B | X, Y, Z |

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try : GroupBy(x => new {user = x.UserIds, permission = x.PermissionIds})

Comment: I dont think so @jdweng, because I want to group the mappings, not the rows.

Comment: In that case you want something else, not grouping. It's unclear what exactly you want, or what the logic is, but it looks like you want to find  the largest set of common permissions and the users that have them? That's a complex set operation, not groupings. If the permissions were ordered, this would be similar to finding the [Longest Common Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) in a set of sequences. There should be algorithms and data structures that accelerate the solution to this problem, just not in LINQ

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos for clarifying its not that simple! :)

Answer (score 2):

One possible apporach is to group, create one object per group, and then regroup the new objects before creating your `Row` objects.

Seeing as you have used characters for `UserId` and `PermissionId` in your example, I am regarding those properties as `char`s in my example.

The idea is roughly:

1. Order by `UserId` (not necessary in your specific example, but otherwise)
2. Group by `PermissionId`
3. Create one object per grouping, containing `PermissionId` and the collection of associated `UserId`s
4. Group the objects by the string created by the `UserId` characters
5. Create one `Row` object per grouping by

   - converting the group key (user ID string) to a list of `char`s
   - extracting all the `PermissionId`s from the group

It could be implemented as follows:

```csharp
List<Row> rows = mappings
    .OrderBy(m => m.UserId)
    .GroupBy(m => m.PermissionId)
    .Select(gr => (
        PermissionId: gr.Key,
        UserIds: gr.Select(m => m.UserId).ToArray() ))
    .GroupBy(permissionForUsers => new string(permissionForUsers.UserIds),
        ( userIds, permissionsForUsers ) => new Row {
            UserIds = userIds.ToList(),
            PermissionIds = permissionsForUsers.Select(m => m.PermissionId).ToList() })
    .ToList();
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/deTaBG).

---

**Suggestion for improving this implementation:**
In the first `.Select()` operation, use a collection implementation for the `UserIds` object field that is comparable, so that the following `.GroupBy()` operation is not dependent on creating a `string` (for the group key) and then transforming the key back to a `char` collection again when creating the `Row` object's `UserIds`.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping the data twice. First by PermissionId, then by the joined string of UserId (eg. 'X,Y'):

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(x => x.PermissionId);

var groups2 = groups.GroupBy(x => string.Join(',', x.Select(g => g.UserId)));

foreach (var group in groups2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key + " - " + string.Join(',', group.Select(g => g.Key)));   
}
```

Note: for this to work, the items need to be sorted by UserId and PermissionId.

Comment: UserId B's permissions are `X,Y,Z` so it won't be grouped together with UserA for XY. You'd have to calculate all possible combinations of permissions and *then* group by permissions.